# Ambiguous use of 'lazy'

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation, overloading, swift4

I have no idea why [this example](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59bd6e6ee43e3c51020a86b1) is ambiguous. (My apologies for not adding the code here, it's simply too long.)

I have added `prefix (_ maxLength)` as an overload to `LazyDropWhileBidirectionalCollection`. `subscript(position)` is defined on `LazyPrefixCollection`. Yet, the following code from the above example shouldn't be ambiguous, yet it is:

```
print([0, 1, 2].lazy.drop(while: {_ in false}).prefix(2)[0]) // Ambiguous use of 'lazy'
```

It is my understanding that an overload that's higher up in the protocol hierarchy will get used.

According to the compiler it can't choose between two types; namely `LazyRandomAccessCollection` and `LazySequence`. (Which doesn't make sense since `subscript(position)` is not a method of `LazySequence`.) `LazyRandomAccessCollection` would be the logical choice here.

If I remove the subscript, it works:

```
print(Array([0, 1, 2].lazy.drop(while: {_ in false}).prefix(2))) // [0, 1]
```

**What could be the issue?**

Comment: The compiler output shows the two possible candidates for `lazy`

Comment: Could you please post the relevant "problem code"?

Comment: @shallowThought The relevant problem code is the last line from the link in the first sentence. I've added it to the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trail here is just too complicated and ambiguous. You can see this by dropping elements. In particular, drop the last subscript:

```
let z = [0, 1, 2].lazy.drop(while: {_ in false}).prefix(2)
```

In this configuration, the compiler wants to type `z` as `LazyPrefixCollection<LazyDropWhileBidirectionalCollection<[Int]>>`. But that isn't indexable by integers. <strike>I know it feels like it should be, but it isn't provable by the current compiler.</strike> (see below) So your `[0]` fails. And backtracking isn't powerful enough to get back out of this crazy maze. There are just too many overloads with different return types, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want.

But this particular case is trivially fixed:

```
print([0, 1, 2].lazy.drop(while: {_ in false}).prefix(2).first!)
```

That said, I would absolutely avoid pushing the compiler this hard. This is all too clever for Swift today. In particular overloads that return different types are very often a bad idea in Swift. When they're simple, yes, you can get away with it. But when you start layering them on, the compiler doesn't have a strong enough proof engine to resolve it. (That said, if we studied this long enough, I'm betting it actually is ambiguous somehow, but the diagnostic is misleading. That's a very common situation when you get into overly-clever Swift.)

---

Now that you describe it (in the comments), the reasoning is straightforward.

`LazyDropWhileCollection` can't have an integer index. Index subscripting is required to be O(1). That's the meaning of the `Index` subscript versus other subscripts. (The `Index` subscript must also return the `Element` type or crash; it can't return an `Element?`. That's way there's a `DictionaryIndex` that's separate from `Key`.)

Since the collection is lazy and has an arbitrary number of missing elements, looking up any particular integer "count" (first, second, etc.) is O(n). It's not possible to know what the 100th element is without walking through at least 100 elements. To be a collection, its O(1) index has to be in a form that can only be created by having previously walked the sequence. It can't be `Int`.

This is important because when you write code like:

```
for i in 1...1000 { print(xs[i]) }
```

you expect that to be on the order of 1000 "steps," but if this collection had an integer index, it would be on the order of 1 million steps. By wrapping the index, they prevent you from writing that code in the first place.

This is especially important in highly generic languages like Swift where layers of general-purpose algorithms can easily cascade an unexpected O(n) operation into completely unworkable performance (by "unworkable" I mean things that you expected to take milliseconds taking minutes or more).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After some digging, the reason `[0]` fails probably has something to do with `drop(while:)` (and `prefix(while:)`) wrapping the underlaying index in a `LazyDropWhileIndex` (and `LazyPrefixWhileIndex`). This is a `struct` which has an implicit `init` (and can therefore not be initialised outside of the standard library). All other types conforming to `LazyCollectionProtocol` don't wrap their indices, but 'forward' the index of the underlying base collection. (There are probably good reasons for the wrapping which I don't fully comprehend yet.)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Some more thoughts. `LazyPrefixWhileIndex` does a cool trick where the `endIndex` disregards the base collection's index and just returns an `enum` value representing the end index in O(1). Writing unit tests for anything involving `LazyPrefixWhileIndex` is impossible since its `init` is implicit and the underlaying value holding the representation of the index is `internal`. With `LazyDropWhileIndex` we at least have access to the `base` index so we can test it against an instance of the base collection's `Index` type.

Comment: In conclusion, I can understand the reasoning behind `LazyPrefixWhileIndex`, but for `LazyDropWhileIndex` they could've just used the underlying base `Index` type.

Comment: How would you implement that in O(1)? You may have to drop the entire collection before you find the first element that isn't dropped. And finding `xs[1]` would likely have to do it all again unless there's is caching (but in any case would still be O(n) because it might have to scan the rest of the collection).

Comment: The last two comments were mostly observations of `LazyDropWhileIndex` and `LazyPrefixWhileIndex`. In the first case the `Index` type doesn't matter as it doesn't do anything 'extra' that any other `Index` type could do. The wrapper is not needed; `LazyDropWhileIndex(1)` is literally the same as `1`, unless I missed something.

Comment: The time complexity issue is very interesting. I doubt we can make any of the lazy implementations of `prefix` and `suffix`-like operations O(1). But indeed, we could optimise them using caching. I feel this is worthy of another question which I've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291603).

Answer (score 0):

Change the last row to this:

```
let x = [0, 1, 2]

let lazyX:  LazySequence                = x.lazy
let lazyX2: LazyRandomAccessCollection  = x.lazy
let lazyX3: LazyBidirectionalCollection = x.lazy
let lazyX4: LazyCollection              = x.lazy

print(lazyX.drop(while: {_ in false}).prefix(2)[0])
```

You can notice that the array has 4 different lazy conformations - you will have to be explicit.

Comment: It is my understanding that the overload that's higher up in the protocol chain will get used.

According to the compiler it can't choose between two types; namely `LazyRandomAccessCollection` and `Sequence`. (Which doesn't make sense since `subscript(position)` is not a method of `Sequence`.)

`LazyRandomAccessCollection` would be the logical choice here in that case.